# Why do I get an exception with "server stack trace" when the client can't even connect to WCF server?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

In my code I make WCF requests to an `https://` endpoint. Sometimes the WCF server will be unreachable for whatever reason and then my code will yield and exception:

```
System.TimeoutException
The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:00.
Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase
the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation
may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
```

and the `.StackTrace` of the exception contains the following text:

```
Server stack trace: <<<< THE QUESTION IS ABOUT THIS VERY LINE
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at [my code here invoking an OperatiionContract-attributed method
```

and the `.InnerException` is another `TimeoutException` with the following message:

```
The HTTP request to 'https://management.core.windows.net/subscription-id-here/
   services/hostedservices/service-name-here/deployments/deployment-id-here'
has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this
operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
```

What I don't get is the `Server stack trace` phrasing.

Why is it "server" if my request hasn't even been responded to by the server?

Comment: Are you sure that client requests do not reached WCF serivce? Perhaps there is some exception on service

Comment: Try increasing any timeouts that are for `1:00` and see if it works any better.

Comment: @John Saunders: Like I'll get an exception not mentioning "server trace"?

Comment: Like you may get a _different_ exception - one different in a tell-tale manner.

Comment: @John Saunders: Well, the problem is definitely no on my side, I just wanted to know why "server stack trace" is mentioned in there.

Comment: Try it and see. In particular, if you get to the server, you'll know that you _can_ get to the server.

Answer (score 0):

A timeout can occur on both sides of the connection; client or server. Therefore based on your exception, I would say that the client connected to the server but because a response was not generated in time (based on the server's bindings for `sendTimeout`), WCF responded as you've seen.

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a bit more info on the timeout settings.